# Пунктуация в сложноподчиненном предложении

Tags: пунктуация

Почему в предложении «Маргарита не могла бы сказать, из чего сделан повод его коня, и думала, что возможно, что это лунные цепочки и самый конь — только глыба мрака, и грива этого коня — туча, а шпоры всадника — белые пятна звезд» не ставится запятая перед «и самый конь», ведь это соподчиненные придаточные с повторяющимся союзом?

Comment: You're right, and of course the comma should be there. Where did you find this sentence without the comma?

Answer (score 3):

The (simplified) sentence structure (the way I see it) is:

> - Маргарита думала, что
>
>   - возможно, что
>
>     - это (*материал повода*) — цепочки
>   - и конь — глыба
>   - и грива — туча
>   - а шпоры — пятна

If you squint *really* hard, there are some other readings possible:

> - Маргарита думала, что
>
>   - возможно, что
>
>     - это (*материал повода*) — цепочки
>     - и конь — глыба
>     - и грива — туча
>     - а шпоры — пятна

or even

> - Маргарита думала, что
>
>   - возможно, что
>
>     - это (*материал повода*) — цепочки
>     - и конь — глыба
>   - и грива — туча
>   - а шпоры — пятна

Only in the last case do you not need the comma because in all the other cases we have a series of dependent clauses separated by repeating coordinating conjunctions. This is covered in Rosenthal's guide, §35.4:

> При повторяющихся сочинительных союзах между соподчиненными придаточными частями сложноподчиненного предложения ставится запятая: *Находясь в госпитале, он вспоминал, как фашисты напали на них внезапно, **и** как они оказались в окружении, **и** как отряду всё же удалось пробиться к своим (Газ).*

What the author's intent was is anyone's guess, but the 1969 Frankfurt-am-Main edition does have the comma:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Именно так: это соподчинённые предложения, соединённые одинарным союзом и. Запятая в таком случае не ставится: Розенталь, параграф 35, пункт 3 - http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=136.

Answer (score 0):

1. **Правильно с запятой:**

Маргарита не могла бы сказать, из чего сделан повод его коня, и думала, что возможно, **что это лунные цепочки, и самый конь — только глыба мрака**, и грива этого коня — туча, а шпоры всадника — белые пятна звезд.

2. **Почему?**  Используем для проверки бессоюзную связь с изъяснительным значением:

*Маргарита не могла бы сказать, из чего сделан повод его коня, и думала, что возможно: **это лунные цепочки, и самый конь — только глыба мрака,** и грива этого коня — туча, а шпоры всадника — белые пятна звезд».*

3. Перед первым предложением союз И может опускаться, как и в случае однородных членов. **[Розенталь, п. 6](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=101#pp101)**

Если однородных членов предложения более двух, а союз повторяется перед каждым из них, кроме первого, то запятая ставится **между всеми однородными членами:** Листья в поле пожелтели, и кружатся, и летят;